# Too many files open error in nextjs production build

Tags: webpack, next.js, build, production

Whenever i'm building my nextjs app using npm run build, it keeps showing me this error,
`Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'D:\Clients\Client 5\goat-moves\node_modules\@mui\icons-material\ShuffleTwoTone.js'       caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'D:\Clients\Client 5\goat-moves\node_modules\@mui\icons-material\ShuffleTwoTone.js'`

My next.config.js file is this,
`/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
distDir: "build",
output: "export",
images: {
unoptimized: true,
},
};

module.exports = nextConfig;`

How can i solve this problem? I am using next.js version 13.3.4 and my os is windows 10.

I am expecting my build file will be in the build directory instead it is showing error.